# What does these inline html comments mean: <!-- build:js ...-->

Tags: gruntjs, yeoman

I am using web yeoman.

In my applications index.html file I have this script includes.

I would like to know what these `<!-- build:js ... -->` mean and from which tool they originate?

I would also be grateful about any source link.

My problem is that I plan a very modularized angularjs app and I do not want to manually add 200 .js files to this index.html file.

Maybe this can be configured that during compiling those script entries can be copied over with a clever algo depending on my app folder structure...

```
<!-- build:js({.tmp,app}) scripts/scripts.js -->
    <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/controllers/main.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/services/factory1.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `build` blocks are from `grunt-usemin`.  It will not automatically scan and add files from a directory.

You can use a task like [grunt-include-source](https://github.com/jwvdiermen/grunt-include-source) to prep the HTML with the files from your scripts directory tree and then run usemin to concat and uglify them.

The `grunt-include-source` github page (linked in the last paragraph) contains examples of `Gruntfile` configurations to update the HTML.  Your main challenge will be the `src` to `dest` juggle as the HTML is updated by multiple tasks.  In the scope of things, compared to dealing with 200+ files, that should still be easier.  The downside, of course, is that if you have any orphan files in your list of 200+...they will still get included and sent.

You can also see these StackOverflow questions where similar questions have been asked:

1. [can grunt automatically include all my js in index.html?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19737516/can-grunt-automatically-include-all-my-js-in-index-html)
2. [How to include scripts automatically in a yeoman/grunt project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21232889/how-to-include-scripts-automatically-in-a-yeoman-grunt-project)

Comment: About the orphan files, could I not create a grunt task which removes the content between the build blocks and THEN read all .JS files from modules/**/*.JS to add them within the build blocks? Then I would have no orphans right?

Comment: Sure. I think there are several reasonable approaches to cleaning up orphan files. Use the one that makes the best sense for your project. :)